# There are 2 datasets for which I am doing inventory analysis. I am not sure on how to implement the logic and code in python and achieve the output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic, analysis

There are 2 datasets for which I am doing raw material analysis.

| MATERIAL | PURCHASE_ORDER | ITEM_NUMBER | SCHEDULE_DATE | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 14-Jul-22 | 100 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 17-Jul-22 | 200 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 18-Jul-22 | 500 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 25-Jul-22 | 150 |

| MATERIAL | PURCHASE_ORDER | ITEM_NUMBER | RECEIPT_DATE | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 19-Jul-22 | 80 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 20-Jul-22 | 120 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 25-Jul-22 | 350 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 27-Jul-22 | 150 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 29-Jul-22 | 200 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 01-Aug-22 | 50 |

The first three columns are common in the both the dataset.

1st Table - SCHEDULE_DATE is the date when delivery of an Item is scheduled whereas QUANTITY is the quantity to be delivered on that date.

2nd Table - RECEIPT_DATE is the actual delivery date and QUANTITY is how much quantity was delivered in that day.

I want below output.
Let's assume 1st row where QTY is taken from 1st row of 1st table and REM_QTY (remaining_qty) is quantity take from 1st row of 2nd table. 
In 2nd row, out of 100, 80 is sold, 20 is remaining which is showed in the 2nd row rem_qty. 
In 3rd row, 100 qty of 1st row - 1st table is fulfilled. Now on 17th Jul-22, 200 is scheduled to be delivered. Hence, QTY is 200 and on 20-Jul-22, out 120, 20 is gone for 1st delivery and 100 is remaining. Hence, remaining is 100

Likewise, I have to perform this activity for rest of the records.

| MATERIAL | PO | ITEM_No. | SCHEDULE_DATE | QTY | RECEIPT_DATE | REM_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 14-Jul-22 | 100 | 19-Jul-22 | 80 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 14-Jul-22 | 100 | 20-Jul-22 | 20 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 17-Jul-22 | 200 | 20-Jul-22 | 100 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 17-Jul-22 | 200 | 25-Jul-22 | 100 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 18-Jul-22 | 500 | 25-Jul-22 | 250 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 18-Jul-22 | 500 | 27-Jul-22 | 150 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 18-Jul-22 | 500 | 29-Jul-22 | 100 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 25-Jul-22 | 150 | 29-Jul-22 | 100 |
| RW1 | P1 | I1 | 25-Jul-22 | 150 | 01-Aug-22 | 50 |

I have been trying to think of a logic with it's implementation in python but not sure on how to do it?

Comment: Table 1 and table 2 are the same image, making answering your question rather difficult. And instead of linking to pictures of your tables, could you provide them (in plain text) in your question itself? That would make things clearer and make it easier to help you.

Comment: Updated for better understanding